# How install and start Exasol community on DigitalOcean droplet?

Tags: database, digital-ocean, analytical, exasol

one of my projects needs a fast analytical database, now I use memsql, I would like to test Exasol, but I still can’t figure out how to deploy it to DigitalOcean droplet, does anyone have any detailed instructions on how to do this?